# Emacs: Visiting files with format path:line:column

Tags: emacs, compilation

When using `visit file` (`'next-error`) from my compilation buffer on a path formatted as `<absolute path>:<line>:<column>`, Emacs cannot find the file. It works perfectly if the column is not present but seems to interpret `:<line>` as part of the filename.

---

**Example:**

Imagine I get the following error:

```
    at moxios.withMock (<absolute path>/<filename>:8:7)
```

Emacs recognizes the path (highlighted in my compilation buffer as follow).

```
    at moxios.withMock ([red]<absolute path>/<filename>:8[/red]:[yellow]7[/yellow])
```

However, when I try to visit the link, Emacs seems to struggle with the `path:line:column` format.

I get prompted with an interractive buffer:

```
Find this error in (default <filename>:8): <an absolute path which is not the path of the file>/
./
../
[...]
```

Do you have any idea how to make sure Emacs recognizes the `<filename>:<line>:<column>` format correctly?

Comment: Probably an issue with one of the regexps in [`compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L164). Each entry is a regexp followed by two numbers, identifying the capture group for the line number and column number, respectively. Perhaps the one that matches the error messages you have doesn't match the column number properly?